# Issue while hosting WCF service on IIS 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7, hosting

I am unable to browser the service which is hosted on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008.

When I hit the url `http://myservice/service1.svc` it throws an error.

Comment: Knowing what the actual error is might help people help you. Or help them help yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure you have framework 3.5 sp1 installed, after this go to Programs, add remove windows features, then make sure you have:

Microsoft .net framework 3.5.1 
under that make sure both options are checked:
WCF HTTP activation, and WCF Non HTTP Activation....

If this still doesn't work update post a comment here....